# How to remove duplicate meta tags in nuxt-js?

Tags: nuxt.js, meta-tags, vue-meta

I am using nuxt `version 2.15.7` in my project. Here is the `nuxt.config.js` file:

```js
export default {
    head: {
        titleTemplate: '%s',
        title: 'info-book',
        meta: [
          {charset: 'utf-8'},
          {name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1'},
          {
            hid: 'description',
            name: 'description',
            template: '%s',
            content: 'this is the main description',
          },
          {name: 'format-detection', content: 'telephone=no'}
        ],
        link: [
            { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }
        ]
    },
    // some other parts
}
```

I want to show the `content` of meta description defined here as a general meta description tag of my website. Then in any page like this dynamic page I want to replace it with the new one:

> code of page in `pages/dastebandi/_idCat/index.vue` folder:

```js
<script>

export default {
 
  head() {
    return {
      title: "info-book - " + this.titleHead,
      meta: [
        {
          hid: this.idCategory,
          name: 'description',
          content: this.descriptionContent
        }
      ]
    }
  },

  data () {
    return {
      categorizedBook: [],
      idCategory: this.$route.params.idCat,
      titleCategory: "",
      titleHead: "",
      descriptionContent: ""
    }
  },

  async fetch() {
    this.categorizedBook = await this.$strapi.$books.find("tags=" + this.idCategory);
    let categoryArr = await this.$strapi.$tags.find("id=" + this.idCategory);
    this.titleCategory = categoryArr[0]["name"];
    this.titleHead = categoryArr[0]["en_name"];
    this.descriptionContent = categoryArr[0]["description"];
  },

}
</script>
```

In the code mentioned above `this.descriptionContent` is some description that comes from database. Also `this.idCategory` is the dynamic `id` of the page and so is unique for each page. The reason that I used `template: '%s',` in my `nuxt.config.js` file is that according to [nuxt docs](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/meta-tags-seo#local-settings), we can use options of [vue-meta](https://vue-meta.nuxtjs.org/api/#meta) in our `head()` settings.

With the descriptions and code above, when I go to my `home-page` and see page source this is the result:

[image: page source of home page]

But when I go to some of the dynamic pages in that folder, here is the page source:

[image: page source of dynamic page]

So why nuxt does not remove the main description in **dynamic pages**? Are my codes wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define your custom meta into a page, you can override the `nuxt.config.js` metas. You have the `hid` attribute to identify each meta, but are overriding the `hid` so you are saying that you want to display a new meta in your dynamic page identified by "4".

So your head must be:

```js
  head() {
    return {
      title: "info-book - " + this.titleHead,
      meta: [
        {
          hid: 'description',
          name: 'description',
          content: this.descriptionContent
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

This description is used for SEO purposes, it must be a friendly user description about your page content so you do not need your description id.

Comment: What you said is **exactly** the opposite of what [nuxt docs](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/meta-tags-seo/#local-settings) says: ```To avoid any duplication when used in child components, please give a **unique** identifier with the hid key to the meta description. This way vue-meta will know that it has to overwrite the default tag.``` In the way you said all ```hid```s must be **description**, so they are not unique.

Comment: Any way the method you said works fine for me, I think I misunderstood the concept of **unique** identifier. It is better that **nuxt docs** replace that with **same** identifier to prevent these kinds of mistake.

Comment: Yeah but this means that your unique identifier is `hid` and not the `name` attribute. I understand you because it is a bit confusing